# Find the output for the series (RC) low pass filter

Tags: filter, low-pass

How can I solve this problem? Sorry if it is too simple but I learn from home due to COVID-19 and can not get in touch with my teachers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a two-step procedure:

1. derive the characteristic function of the RC filter. Step-, impulse-response, or transfer characteristic. Depending on which one you have learnt about so far.
2. Use the operation for the given characteristic function.

PS: I've not learnt this in English, please feel free to correct my nomenclature.